# C# MongoClient throws DnsResponseException after second request

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-mvc, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-atlas

I have a MongoDB on Atlas which I'm querying from my ASP.NET Core MVC app.

In my Context class I'm initializing the MongoClient from the constructor like this:

```
var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
if (client != null)
{
    _database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.DatabaseName);
}
```

The repository class is being injected into my controller as a Transient service

```
services.AddTransient<IMovieRepository, MovieRepository>();
```

If I try to get something from a collection out of this db, everything works fine on the first try. If I refresh my page, it tries to create the MongoClient again and fails throwing me a `DnsResponseException`. After that I have to wait a minute or so and it works again once. Robo3T lets me do as many consecutive queries as I wish, so the problem could only be on the C# MongoClient I guess...

Here's the full exception I'm getting:

```
;; Error: Cannot read byte 269, out of range.
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot read byte 269, out of range.
   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadByte()
   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadLabels()
   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadQuestionQueryString()
   at DnsClient.DnsRecordFactory.ReadRecordInfo()
   at DnsClient.DnsMessageHandler.GetResponseMessage(ArraySegment`1 responseData)
   at DnsClient.DnsUdpMessageHandler.Query(IPEndPoint server, DnsRequestMessage request, TimeSpan timeout)
   at DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers, DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, Boolean useCache, LookupClientAudit continueAudit)
;; Error: Cannot read byte 269, out of range.
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot read byte 269, out of range.
   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadByte()
   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadLabels()
   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadQuestionQueryString()
   at DnsClient.DnsRecordFactory.ReadRecordInfo()
   at DnsClient.DnsMessageHandler.GetResponseMessage(ArraySegment`1 responseData)
   at DnsClient.DnsUdpMessageHandler.Query(IPEndPoint server, DnsRequestMessage request, TimeSpan timeout)
   at DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers, DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, Boolean useCache, LookupClientAudit continueAudit)
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this exception and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the error for 3 days, already desperate changed my DNS setting to:

[image]

Solved! ‍♂️